# Button setOnClickListener with AlertDialog not working

Tags: android

public class Anime extends Activity {

```
private Button button;  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};              
            //Toast.makeText(Anime.this, "KKKKKKK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Anime.this);              
            builder.setTitle("Pick a color"); 
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { 
                    Toast.makeText(Anime.this,"jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                } 
            }); 
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); 
        } 
    });     

}
```

}

I have the code just to display the AlertDialog. It doesn't work. But the toast which i comment it out is working well. Don't get it.

Thanks for show()!
It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to show your dialog =)

```
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `alert.show()` to display your alert.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to call `.show()` on the alert. Try this after `AlertDialog alert = builder.create();` :

```
alert.show();
```